# In intellij, does a project constitute a single classpath?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I have two grails projects (on different versions of grails), but they work together to provide a seemless user experience.   Can IntelliJ have a single project which has both grails projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some terminology clarifications:

- What you're calling a project, IntelliJ calls a module. An IntelliJ module typically generates a single artifact (.war, .jar, etc). The Eclipse equivalent of an IntelliJ module is a project.
- An IntelliJ project is a grouping of related modules. The Eclipse equivalent of an IntelliJ project is a workspace

So what you probably want to do is create a IntelliJ project, which contains two modules (one for each Grails app). IntelliJ will allow you to add two Grails modules that use different versions of Grails to the same project. Each IntelliJ module has its classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can add it as a new module to current project/workspace: `File -> New Module`